# How to plot a 2D region defined by inequalities at a specific level in 3D plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

I really looked to all the posts that I could find but couldn't get what I need.

I have sets of  inequalities like this;

-2.3 + 6.8 i < d && 3.50 + 0.05 i > d

Which is used to plot the region as follow.

```
twod = RegionPlot[-2.3 + 6.8 i < d && 3.50 + 0.05 i > d, {i, 0, 10}, {d, -15, 15}, Axes -> False, Frame -> False, Background -> None]
```

[image]
Then I need to plot this 2D region plot at vertical axis equal to 0.5 which is defined by variable p;

Eventually I want to come up with such a plot;
[image]

Comment: Have you seen `RegionFunction`?

Comment: I don't fully understand: you have inequalities in 2D and want to plot them in - what appears - a nontrivial way in 3D. Where in those equalities is the `0.5` you mention? How does the region depend on `p`?

Comment: @corey979 for p=0.5 I have 1 set of inequalities and for another p I have another inequalities. Thus p is discrete.

Comment: @J.M. While I have those inequalities to define region. I found the only option to use with RegionFunction is parametricplot3d which yields non-smooth surfaces. Like this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99BO2.jpg)

Comment: How about sth like `Table[RegionPlot3D[
   x^2 + y^2 <= p, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, p, p + 1}], {p, 1, 
   9}] // Show[#, PlotRange -> All] &`? You can have `p` stored in some list and can build such `Table` refering to that list to define the heights of each region.

Comment: There is no p in inequalities in my case. And what is z in your suggestion? And I don't have any height for the planes. :/